# Selected range to occupy full page on Print Preview

Tags: vba, excel

I am showing the print preview for a selected range. There is a lot of blank space on the page. I would like that my range occupies the whole page.

```
Sub Print_preview()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").PageSetup

  .PrintArea = "d5:s33"

  .FitToPagesTall = 2

  .FitToPagesWide = 1

End With

PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: The blank space is because the size of the range does not fit well onto the size of a page.  This is usually resolved by changing row or column sizes to get things to even out.  Other options include changing the paper size or forcing things to fit on 1 page instead of the 2 pages above.